# iMessage app - When inserting a message "nil" error is printed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imessage, imessage-extension

```
conversation.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
    print(error as Any)
})
```

Above code is used while creating a picture to be sent as a message in an iMessage app. "nil" is being printed in the log. Would that be a problem?

Because any further interaction with the app, crashes it. Not sure if these are related!

Answer (score 1):

If `error` is `nil` there is no error at all, the operation succeeded.

The reason of the crash must be somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for clearing my doubts. I should go search elsewhere. Guess, it's AutoLayoutConstraints..!!